# Haskell. MongoDB driver  or Aeson charset problem

Tags: haskell, mongodb

Good day, i have mongodb database filled with some data, i ensured that data stored in correct charset, to fetch data i use following snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import Data.Enumerator (Iteratee (..))
import Data.Either (either)
import Control.Monad (join)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Network.HTTP.Types (statusOK, status404)
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Data.Text (Text(..))
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO, MonadIO)
import Data.Aeson (encode)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Database.MongoDB as DB

application dbpipe req = do
  case unpack $ rawPathInfo req of
    "/items" -> itemsJSON dbpipe req
    _ ->  return $ responseLBS status404 [("Content-Type", "text/plain")] "404"

indexPage :: Iteratee B.ByteString IO Response
indexPage = do
  page <- liftIO $ processTemplate "templates/index.html" []
  return $ responseLBS statusOK [("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")] page

processTemplate f attrs = do
  page <- L.readFile f
  return page

itemsJSON :: DB.Pipe -> Request -> Iteratee B.ByteString IO Response
itemsJSON dbpipe req = do
  dbresult <- liftIO $  rundb dbpipe $ DB.find (DB.select [] $ tu "table") >>= DB.rest
  let docs = either (const []) id dbresult
--  liftIO $ L.putStrLn $ encode $ show $ map docToMap docs
  return $ responseLBS statusOK [("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")]
    (encode $ map docToMap docs)

docToMap doc = Map.fromList $ map (\f -> (T.dropAround (== '"') $ T.pack $ show $ DB.label f, T.dropAround (== '"') $ T.pack $ show $ DB.value f)) doc


main =  do
  pipe <- DB.runIOE $ DB.connect $ DB.host "127.0.0.1"
  run 3000 $ application pipe

rundb pipe act = DB.access pipe DB.master database act

tu :: B.ByteString -> UString
tu = DB.u . C8.unpack
```

Then the result is suprprising, DB.label works well, but DB.value giving me native characters as some escape codes, so the result is look like:

`curl http://localhost:3000/items` gives:

```
[{"Марка": "\1058\1080\1087 \1087\1086\1076",
  "Model": "BD-W LG BP06LU10 Slim \1058\1080\1087 \1087\1086\1076\1082\1083\1102\1095\1077\1085\1080\1103"},
 ...
]
```

This happens in case i trying to print data and also in case i return data encoded as JSON
Any idea how correctly extract values from MongoDB driver ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line confirms that aeson's encoding works properly (using the utf8-string library to read utf8 data off the lazy bytestring back to a haskell string:

```
> putStrLn $ Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8.toString $ encode $ ("\1058\1080\1087 \1087\1086\1076",12)
["Тип под",12]
```

Looking at your code more closely I see the real problem. You're calling `T.pack $ show $ DB.value` -- this will render out as literal codepoints, and then pack those into a text object. The fix is to switch from show to something smarter. Look at this (untested)

```
smartShow :: DB.Value -> Text
smartShow (String s) = Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8 $ Data.CompactString.UTF8.toByteString s
smartShow x = T.pack $ show x
```

Obviously to handle the recursive cases, etc. you need to be smarter than that, but that's the general notion...

In fact, the "best" thing to do is to write a function of `BSON -> JSON` directly, rather than go through any intermediate structures at all.

Comment: I see you proposing correct solution, but couldn't get your snippets work for my case, for example why String constructor is used for DB.Value type ?

Comment: @Dfr: Because that's the name of the constructor used by bson, which is what a `Value` is: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bson/0.1.6/doc/html/Data-Bson.html

Comment: I'm not going to install the mongodb bindings right now, so sorry that this code isn't tested. The gist should be correct, however.

Comment: Thank you, that finally worked with `smartShow`, im afraid my haskell knowledge is yet too poor to make generic BSON->JSON function.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working as expected -- only your expectations are wrong. =)

What you're seeing there are not raw `String`s; they are `String`'s which have been escaped to exist purely in the printable ASCII range by the `show` function, called by `print`:

```
print = putStrLn . show
```

Never fear: in memory, the string that `print`s as `"\1058"` is in fact a single Unicode codepoint long. You can observe this by printing the length of one of the `String`s you're interested in and comparing that to the number of Unicode codepoints you expect.

Comment: Thank you, this is good explanaiton, but i still don't realise how to get normal strings from database. I tried DB.cast, but it also do not work. Or maybe simpler case is how to convert MongoDB `UString` to `Text`

Comment: I don't know, I haven't used that library. But to my eye, it looks like the code you pasted above already converts to `String` just fine. The problem lies in calling `print` (rather than `putStrLn` or similar), not in the database interface.

Comment: My app hands result to aeson's encode and resulting JSON data also filled with that codepoints, which is not acceptable. User needs just plain UTF8 strings, not escape codes.

Comment: @Dfr Perhaps you'd better make another question, with a pared-down example of some aeson code that doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @Dfr the edited version still doesn't show the issue with json directly.